# Multi-Cell Column Width constrained by adjacent Single-Cell Row in CSS Table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to create a site layout using css and divs with the following criteria:

1. Top and bottom element must occupy 100% width
2. Top element is a single "table-cell"
3. Bottom element must be split vertically into 2 "table-cell" sub-elements, and all fit under the Top element (nothing sticking out and no space between)

It should be simple enough to do with table-styled divs, but I've been fiddling for hours trying to get the bottom element to quit copying its width from the leftmost cell in the top element.  Please help!

Here is my **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/273MW/)**

Note that the "STUFF" cell is pushing the next row's second column to the right.  This prevents things from "fitting" underneath the top row.

HTML:

```
    <div id="dvStructure_Outer">
    <div id="dvStructure_Upper">
        <div id="dvUperrCell">
            STUFFSTUFFSTUFFSTUFFSTUFFSTUFFSTUFFSTUFFSTUFFSTUFFSTUFF<br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dvStructure_Lower">
        <div id="dvDetailStructure_Left">
            Lower Left<br />
        </div>
        <div id="dvDetailStructure_Right">
            <div class="dvDetailSection">
                Lower Right Right Detail 1<br />
            </div>
            <div class="dvDetailSection">
                Lower Right Right Detail 2<br />
            </div>
            <div class="dvDetailSection">
                Lower Right Right Detail 3<br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

STYLE

```css
#dvStructure_Outer {
    display:table;
    min-width:500px;
    border-color:red;
    border:solid; 
}
#dvStructure_Upper {
    display:table-row;
    border:dashed;
}
#dvStructure_Lower {
    display:table-row;
    border:dashed;
}
#dvUperrCell {
    vertical-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    border:dashed;
}
#dvDetailStructure_Left {
    display:table-cell;
    border:dashed;
}
#dvDetailStructure_Right {
    display:table-cell;
    width:400px;
    border:dashed;
}
.dvDetailSection {
    display:table-row;
    border:dotted;
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle didn't generate a correct link, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/273MW/85/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike HTML tables, CSS tables do not have column or row spans. To make the top row span the distance of the 2 cells in the bottom row, the bottom cells were nested in an additional CSS table.

Here is a simplified JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/pewywx4y/ Notice how the top row now fills the entire width of the table.

Sitepoint has a book called "Everything You Know About CSS is Wrong" that covers CSS table layouts, and it states:

> CSS tables lack any concept of row or column spanning, making it trickier to use one single layout structure than what might have been possible when using HTML tables. However, similar layouts can be achieved by using nested CSS tables.

HTML

```
<div class="table short-width">

<div class="table-row">
<div class="table-cell green"><p>Top Row</p></div>    
</div>

<div class="table-row">
<div class="table-cell">    
<div class="table full-width">
<div class="table-row">    
<div class="table-cell peach"><p>Bottom Row Left</p></div>
<div class="table-cell purple"><p>Bottom Row Right</p></div>      
</div>
</div>    
</div> 
</div> 

</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {display:table;}
.table-row {display:table-row;}
.table-cell {display:table-cell;}
.short-width {min-width:500px;}
.full-width {width:100%;}
.green {background-color:#ccffcc;}
.peach {background-color:#ffcccc;}
.purple {background-color:#ccccff;}
p {margin:0; padding:.5em;}
```